# Private data collection in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Which database is used to store the private data in Hyperledger fabric? Is it the same instance of statedB as used while storing public data or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's by default uses leveldb provided by fabric as like as ledger.
unless you choose couchdb for your network.

Answer (score 0):

Private state data will be saved to the same state database as the public state data. If you choose CouchDB as the state database, the private data will also go to CouchDB. This enables the same queries against private data as public data.